# Using Report speech

Tags: past-tense, reported-speech

Am I using report speech correctly?

Should I have used present simple in this situation?

I brother to help me. I said that "this was up your alley". He said that "he would help" and wrote some code and said "let's saw what we came out of this"

Comment: It's all wrong. *I asked my brother to help me. I said [that] this was [right] up his alley. He said [that] he would help. He wrote some code and said "Let's see what [happens with] this"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Thanks! I was wondering can i use "what is gonna come out of this" instead "what happens with this"?

Comment: I suggest you learn the basics of "standard" English before you start delving into quirky / slangy usages such as *What's **gonna** come [out] of this?*

Answer (score 1):

When you report speech, don't use quote marks " "

In a direct quote, you use quote marks

> He said, "this was up your alley".

But when reporting speech you don't

> He said that he would help.

"Let's" is always followed by the infinitive, never the past tense. Never say "let's saw". Never say "let's sees".  Always "let's see".

Now  "Let's see" is an imperative form of "let" You can't use imperatives in reported speech. You have to describe the meaning

> He said, "play tennis" ->  He told me to play tennis.

"let's" is used to make suggestions so we need that word.

> He wrote, "Let's see what comes out this" -> He suggested in writing that we see what comes out of this.

You need to rewrite:

> I asked my brother to help me, but he told me it was up my alley.  He offered to help but suggested I started by writing some code and seeing how it turns out.

Comment: I'm quite sure he ***didn't*** say "this was up your alley". Disregarding the lack of capitalization, he almost certainly said "This **is** [right] up your alley".

Comment: He could also have ended it with, "he offered to help but said I should write some code and we'd see how that would turn out."